# Strange behaviour when evaluating $\int x^n (x-1)^m$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have tried evaluating the integral in the title in two different ways.
First by giving explicit (integer) values for $n,m$ before evaluating, and
second by integrating for general $n,m$, and then plugin these values. I shockingly get different answers.
What is happening? (I am using Mathematica 13.1.0 on MacOS)

```
Integrate[x^n (x - 1)^m, x] /. {n -> 2, m -> 3, x -> 4}
(* Out: 4779/20 *)
Integrate[x^2 (x - 1)^3, x] /. x -> 4
(* Out: 3584/15 *)
```

Comment: I think the confusion stems from substituting a value for x. Looking at `Integrate[x^n (x-1)^m, x] /. {n -> 2, m -> 3} // Expand` and comparing it to `Integrate[x^2 (x-1)^3, x]`, you will notice that the two outputs differ only by a constant, so they are both viable antiderivatives of your function.

Comment: `D[Integrate[x^2 (x - 1)^3, x, GeneratedParameters -> l], x] == 
  D[Integrate[x^n (x - 1)^m, x, GeneratedParameters -> k] /. {n -> 2, 
     m -> 3}, x] // Simplify`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indefinite integral is only defined up to a constant. Therefore, you should not compere the results directly, but you must compare the difference:

Let us define 2 function obtained by the 2 methods:

```
f1[x_] = Integrate[x^n (x - 1)^m, x] /. {n -> 2, m -> 3}
f2[x_] = Integrate[x^2 (x - 1)^3, x]
```

If we now plot the difference, we see that it is very small in the range of machine number errors:

```
Plot[{f1[x] - f2[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

To make it more convincing, we may calculate the difference analytically:

```
f1[x] - f2[x] // Simplify

(*1/60*)
```

And we see that it is really a constant.

Answer (score 4):

Why not `Trace` it?

[image]

In my angle of view, what matters here is the "Constant" in the Output of an Integration. Only definite intergals have a definited answer——so the method to the "+C"  influences the output of an indefinite integration——there can be multiple answers given by mma.
But why doesn't mma choose the same Constant that is 0 in the two examples? See:

It chose 0, but the Answer without Constant are different(but they lead to the same result when dintt)

One is

```mathematica
((-1 + x)^(1 + m)*Hypergeometric2F1[1 + m, -n, 2 + m, 1 - x])/ (1 + m)
```

——which make sense to every `m` and `n`.

The other is just `-(x^3/3) + (3 x^4)/4 - (3 x^5)/5 + x^6/6`, with specific `m` and `n`.

Try to subtract these two when m and n are given. The difference is just a C.

Not familiar with English as a Chinese middleschool student, hope will forgive me :D